# How to use non-contiguous range arguments in Excel's XIRR?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2011

The XIRR requires range arguments. I would like to know how I can somehow use 'split' ranges which are in different locations. Perhaps the picture explains it better. What do I enter in F7, if I want to use the D-G ranges as input?

[image]

I'm looking for a solution that does not create a dummy range elsewhere.

Comment: Built-in functions doesn't support non-contiguous range arguments, however that can be different for UDFs. Best way is to contact the author of that function.

Comment: FYI, Choose function where they used {1,2} didn't work for me.http://forum.chandoo.org/threads/xirr-for-non-contiguous-data-solved.7022/

Comment: Thanks @Sun. Your link put me on the path to something that works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now see that I can use ArrayUnion from http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/691533-combine-two-named-ranges-into-3rd-named-range.html

`Function ArrayUnion(ParamArray Arg() As Variant) As Variant
' Code: Juan Pablo González
' Spec: Aladin Akyurek
' May 4, 2003
' Ref: TinyURL.com - shorten that long URL into a tiny URL
Dim TempUnion() As Variant
Dim i As Long, Itm As Variant, Ctr As Long
For i = LBound(Arg) To UBound(Arg)
Arg(i) = Arg(i)
If IsArray(Arg(i)) Then
For Each Itm In Arg(i)
Ctr = Ctr + 1
ReDim Preserve TempUnion(1 To Ctr) As Variant
TempUnion(Ctr) = Itm
Next Itm
Else
Ctr = Ctr + 1
ReDim Preserve TempUnion(1 To Ctr) As Variant
TempUnion(Ctr) = Arg(i)
End If
Next i
ArrayUnion = TempUnion
End Function`

[image]